# Ruby on rails app not deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, heroku, deployment

I am very new to development in general and am following Michael Hartl's rails book. My 'toy app' works perfectly on my local server but for some reason when I try to deploy it through Heroku, I get an error code H10 and the description is "app crashed".

I've got no idea what to do to fix this and have consulted many similar questions across forums but none of the answers seem to work for me. When trying to deploy initially I got a "push rejected" message but after running bundle update everything seemed to process perfectly, except I cannot view the app through heroku.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
Here's the full build-log from the deployment:

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Using rake 12.3.0
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Using minitest 5.10.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using builder 3.2.3
       Using erubi 1.7.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Using crass 1.0.3
       Using rack 2.0.3
       Using nio4r 2.2.0
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Using mini_mime 1.0.0
       Using arel 8.0.0
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Using execjs 2.7.0
       Using method_source 0.9.0
       Using thor 0.20.0
       Using ffi 1.9.18
       Using multi_json 1.12.2
       Using pg 0.21.0
       Using puma 3.11.0
       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
       Using tilt 2.0.8
       Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
       Using i18n 0.9.1
       Using tzinfo 1.2.4
       Using nokogiri 1.8.1
       Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
       Using mail 2.7.0
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using uglifier 4.1.2
       Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Using turbolinks 5.0.1
       Using activesupport 5.1.4
       Using loofah 2.1.1
       Using rack-test 0.8.2
       Using sprockets 3.7.1
       Using sass-listen 4.0.0
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using sass 3.5.4
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using globalid 0.4.1
       Using activemodel 5.1.4
       Using jbuilder 2.7.0
       Using actionview 5.1.4
       Using activejob 5.1.4
       Using activerecord 5.1.4
       Using actionpack 5.1.4
       Using actioncable 5.1.4
       Using actionmailer 5.1.4
       Using railties 5.1.4
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Using rails 5.1.4
       Using sass-rails 5.0.7
       Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (2.73s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       Asset precompilation completed (1.54s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.3.4'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 37.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v11
       https://still-everglades-21863.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Can you post the full build logs from your deployment?

Comment: Have you checked heroku's logs for your app? You can use their command line tool to retrieve logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval.

Comment: I've edited the question to include full build log.. Heroku's logs return the app crashed messsage Error code H10

Comment: did you do `heroku run rake db:migrate` after pushing? This build log you show doesn't have an error btw, only warnings

Comment: When I do heroku run rake db:migrate I get the following error "Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile," but sqlite3 is in my Gemfile?

Comment: did you add sqlite3 gem under some group on your gem file? The gem is not present on log file posted bundle installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite stores data in a file. Heroku doesn't allow storing user's file so you can't use SQLite with Heroku. Instead you should to switch to another database like PostgreSQL or MySQL. [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database) you can find details.

Comment: I've followed all those steps and now when i run "git push heroku" it processes just fine, but when i run "heroku run rails db:migrate," the following message comes up: "PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: It seems the database just hadn't been created in heroku yet. After I created the database everything worked fine. Sorry for being such a noob. Thanks for the help!